# How to change an attribute in layout mvc 5

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm wondering what is the best way to Get information from three tables. What I want to show is a count of all employees by project, and link it with the project name and pnumber.  I find which employee is on which project from WORKS_ON tbl, which holds a record of Essn (matching with EMPLOYEE TABLE WITH SNN) and Pno (MATCHING WITH PROJECT Ttables pnumber).
I did this:

```
Select pno, count(*) as empnum
FROM WORKS_ON work inner join employee emp inner join project
on work.essn=emp.ssn
group by work.pno
where pnumber in 
(select pno from WORKS_ON)
```

I know this is wrong, but not sure where to go.

EDIT:
I then tried

```
SELECT
project, employee
inner join works_on on WORKS_ON.essn = EMPLOYEE.SSN
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON on works_on.pno = PROJECT.pnumber
GROUP BY
PROJECT.Pnumber
```

but still no go.  It says project.pnumber invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  You need to join the project table, which looks like this

```
SELECT
    PROJECT.PNUmber, 
    COUNT(*)
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON on EMPLOYEE.SSN = WORKS_ON.essn
INNER JOIN PROJECT on WORKS_ON.pno = PROJECT.pnumber
GROUP BY PROJECT.Pnumber
```